How can I achieve a similar indirect illumination like in the cassini image from saturn

On the left you can see my version in Blender, on the right is the original image taken by Cassini from Saturn against the backdrop of the sun.
On the original image the indirect illumination from the rings on the planet is clearly visible, possibly also scattered light in the atmosphere that bounces to the dark side of the planet.
My Blender planet also consists of a thick volumetric ball with a physically correct falloff in density. I increased light bounces to 64 both total and for volumes, but I can't achieve a similar effect.
Does anyone have an idea as to how this could be achieved in Blender - preferably using realistic physical properties rather than workarounds, as this is for a procedural planet generator and should always work correctly for all planets created.
Thank you for your help!

I overlooked the Fast GI Approximation.
Once turned off, global illumination worked physically correct and the effect was achieved.
